# publish only some topics of a rosbag file (Command line or launch file)

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosbag, namespace, play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I am using rosbag play in  a launch file, and one of the recorded topics is processed data from the other topics. As I want to produce again, I would like to play all topics except that one.

I know I should have given it an anonymous name or I can play it in a namespace. But I would like just not to have that topic playing.

Thanks!

Cristian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43615/publish-only-some-topics-of-a-rosbag-file-(command-line-or-launch-file)/) by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2012-09-11

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another option would be to create another bag file without the unwanted topic using 'rosbag filter'

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Producing%20filtered%20bag%20files

---

Originally posted by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) with karma: 395 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They hacky version would be to remap this somewhere, e.g. `rosbag play ... my_topic:=my_topc_dev_null_no_one_will_subscribe_this`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7